How to develop and debug app relying on getDigitalGoodsService
I have a PWA, I want to use Gooogle play billing there.
I need to use Digital Goods API for that. It needs an object called getDigitalGoodsService in window.
getDigitalGoodsService is only available in a TWA enviroment (in an app on Android phone).
My question is - how to develop it? Do I need to deploy every single change and test it on my phone? Can I somehow enable getDigitalGoodsService on localhost to do normal development?
It works when I deploy it - the getDigitalGoodsService is there, but I cannot find a way to enable it on localhost. Even if I open localhost from my phone (using local IP) - it doesn't work as it's not a TWA enviroment
